# I have a for with a gulp.watch, but it doesnt work correctly

Tags: javascript, automation, gulp, task, gulp-watch

I need help.
I have this code. I have many sources and i don't use n*source watchs.
I thinked that a for can be a solution, but the watch is instantiated and it dont read my source[i].

You can say some solutions.

Thnks!

```
var base_source = '../';
var source = ['dir1', 'dir2'];
var allFiles = '/**/*';
var dest = '../dist';

gulp.task('default', function () {

      for(var i = 0; i < source.length ; i++) {
        var watchW = base_source + source[i] + allFiles;

        gulp.watch(watchW, function(obj){
          copyFiles(watchW, dest , obj);
        });

      }
    }
```

Edit: I need the source[i] in copyFiles function

Sorry for my english ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to explain why your code doesn't work.  As you can see only the last index "i" is bound to **all** watch functions.  This is known as the "reference problem".  All your watch functions are using, by reference, the same index i.  See, for example, [referencing last index in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902748/javascript-loop-referencing-last-number-in-loop).

Using @OverZealous's answer as guidance in [creating gulp tasks in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968516/creating-tasks-using-a-loop-gulp) here is a solution  for you:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// changed to up one directory
var base_source = './';

// changed variable name slightly for clarity
var sources = ['dir1', 'dir2'];
var allFiles = '/**/*';

// changed to up one directory
var dest = './dist';

var watchSources = Object.keys(sources);

gulp.task('default', function () {

  watchSources.forEach(function (index) {

    var watchW = base_source + sources[index] + allFiles;

    gulp.watch(watchW, function (obj) {
      copyFiles(watchW, dest, obj);
    });
  });
});

function copyFiles(watched, to, obj)  {
  console.log("watched = " + watched);
}
```

Comment: Thnks!! Your answer and the @OverZealous's answer open my mind.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you find my answer correct and helpful please accept as correct so others know it worked.  Thank you.